# Connected to AWS AMI instance but how can I use Jupyter notebook now?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am connected to `AWS AMI` uaing ``Putty`and when I do`conda env list`it shows me all the environments. even the jupyter notebook get started when I do`jupyter notebook`, it shows me:

```
[I 08:00:27.549 NotebookApp] Using EnvironmentKernelSpecManager...
[I 08:00:27.550 NotebookApp] Started periodic updates of the kernel list (every 3 minutes).
[I 08:00:27.778 NotebookApp] Loading IPython parallel extension
[I 08:00:27.808 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 08:00:27.809 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 08:00:27.974 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 08:00:27.975 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu
[I 08:00:27.975 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 08:00:27.975 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/
[I 08:00:27.975 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 08:00:27.979 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[I 08:00:27.979 NotebookApp] Starting initial scan of virtual environments...
[I 08:00:29.943 NotebookApp] Found new kernels in environments: conda_aws_neuron_pytorch_p36, conda_python3, conda_mxnet_latest_p37, conda_aws_neuron_mxnet_p36, conda_pytorch_p36, conda_tensorflow2_latest_p37, conda_tensorflow2_p36, conda_tensorflow_p37, conda_anaconda3, conda_mxnet_p36, conda_aws_neuron_tensorflow_p36, conda_pytorch_latest_p37
```

How can I access `Notebook` running on AWS in my Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notebook is listening on `localhost` on the instance on port 8888 (`http://localhost:8888`). It is accessible only from within instnace, unless you want to fully expose port 8888, which is not a good practice.

The better way is though **ssh tunnel**. Thus, you would establish an ssh tunnel using `putty` between your local machine and your instance. There are many tutorials on how to do it in `putty`. Here is one example:

- [How to run Jupyter Notebooks on remote server — SSH](https://medium.com/@apbetahouse45/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks-on-remote-server-part-1-ssh-a2be0232c533)

In the tutorial you would use port `8888` instead of `1234` which they show. Once the tunnel is up, you can access your notebook in the browser as `http://localhost:8888`.

Another example on accessing notebooks though ssh tunnel using `putty` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276612/remote-access-jupyter-notebook-from-windows).

Comment: But why am i not even getting a notebook url? There is no url which I can access.

Comment: @Deshwal The url is `http://localhost:8888`, but this will work only from within instance.

Comment: No no...not that one. The `Token` you always get. I did not even get the token.

Comment: @Deshwal Don't know about the token. Maybe its disabled? token is something that may or may not be used.

Comment: Yeah! there was some problem for port forwarding. I was using password that's why it wasn't showing any tokens. One more general query, If I run a script there and close the connection (Network Error) or close Putty (same thing), will my script  keep running there?

Comment: @Deshwal Yes, it should be still running on condition that your jupyter is running. So you can run it in `tmux` or `screen` which will persist it if you logout or disconnect. But anyway, this is something that can be easily checked when you run your script.

Comment: No what I meant to ak is that if I run a Jupyter notebook, let it run for 2 days, come back, how can I check the results there? I mean how can I see the progress? I can't be connected for 24 hours for 2 days.