# Error when open Jupyter Notebook from putty

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'am trying to open Jupyter Notebook from Putty. I have a server where is installed Python and Jupyter. I followed all the steps from this post [Remote access Jupyter notebook from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276612/remote-access-jupyter-notebook-from-windows) but it doesn't work. I got the error: This site can't be reached.

Any idea?

Thx

edit: I added a photo with the ps from putty and the error from browser. It's said:

> This site can't be reached

.
[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The good old logout/reboot mechanisms work in this case too!
You can try closing the jupyter connection in the tunnel's connection, logout from the remote server, re-connect and try. Has worked a few times for me today.

If that doesn't work, there might be stale jupyter notebook processes on the remote server. Query for them and kill them and then logout-log back in and try.

If that still does not work, try implementing your code through ipython to check if Jupyter is working at all, even if its user interface isn't loading on your browser.